# Responsive height for React Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am using React LineChart. For the same, I need to have dynamic height as the charts might change in heights based on some other criteria.  If I am giving the height to **LineChart** or using **ResponsiveContainer**, In cases where the Line Chart is not as long as the height applied to it, There is some gap showing between its above DIV and itself, however if the graphs are long enough, the gap does not exists.

Please suggest if I can do anything for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the height of the container element dynamically via clientHeight and set it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight